# LIKE And AS Text Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to run a query in MySQL that will do the following:

1. Search for any number that begins with 5 and have the result in a column labeled classRef and the resulting text be FOO
2. If that number begins with anything other than 5 have it output to the column classRef and the resulting text be BAR.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
ara.AddressNumber AS ExternalID,
ara.AddressNumber as tranId,
cus.Name AS customerRef,
cus.ExternalID LIKE '5%' AS classRef,
cus.ExternalID NOT LIKE '5%' AS classRef2,
'1' AS itemLine_quantity,
'0' AS itemLine_salesPrice

FROM
adrun_copy ara,
customers_copy cus

WHERE
ara.AAccountNumber = cus.ExternalID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN cus.ExternalID LIKE '5%' THEN 'FOO' ELSE 'BAR' END As classRef
```

If that really is a numeric column like `int`, you may need to `CAST` it to a varchar first... not sure on MySql's rules about that.